# how to use load previous page in webview on click backspace button

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am working on a Swing application using javaFX. I have to display html files in webview its working like browser that is ok. i have to display the encrypted file after decryption . When i click on the hyperlink then new file opens in the webview so for hyperlink to get the path of the new file i have added change event with the webview control.

But after applying this back button has stopped working to go to the previous page.

Is there any other way to generate the change event with backspace button in  keyboard so that previous page could be loaded in the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
 backwardButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          int sizeHistory = engine.getHistory().getEntries().size();
          if(sizeHistory>1)
          {
              Entry entry = engine.getHistory().getEntries().get(sizeHistory-2);
              System.out.println("URL hist.: " + entry.getUrl());
              loadURL(entry.getUrl());
          }
        }
     });
```

Since the current visited page is listed in the Entries at the lastPosition (sizeHistory-1), you will need to access the  one index before (sizeHistory-2) in order to get the last visited page.